# Count by 2 categories MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table category_product with id_category and id_product fields. What i want to get is COUNT of all products depending on the category they belong to. The problem is certain product must be in 2 categories on the same hierachical level. Categories structure looks like this:
[image]

Series is basically categorization of products by same design but different purpose.
So i'm in on the Kitchen category page i want to list out number of products by series (something like this (A(10 products), C(12 products)) but they all have to be Kitchen products.

Lets say Kitchen has id of 1 and A, B, C have id's of 10, 11, 12.
If category_product table would look something like this:

```
id_category | id_product
-------------------------
1           | 1
1           | 2
1           | 3
1           | 4
1           | 5
2           | 6
2           | 7
10          | 1
10          | 4
10          | 6
10          | 7
11          | 2
12          | 3
12          | 5
```

On Kitchen category page result should be: 
    A(2), B(1), C(2)

On Bathroom category page (id_category = 2)  result should be:
    A(2), B(0), C(0)

I just can't figure out how to solve this.

Comment: I see no relationship here between 'a', b', and 'c', and anything else. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

By using nested select you can get all the id_product that are in the kitchen category (1), then you can do a select on this result and group by id_category to get how many in each category there is...

`select id_category, count(*) from (select id_product from category_product where id_category=1) group by id_category`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by strawberry, there is no relation indicated between the categories.

Although the following query may give you the result you need in this scenario, it will probably fail to if you have more categories, and more levels in your hierarchy.

```
SELECT
    pt.id_category,
    count(DISTINCT pt.id_product)
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
            id_product
        FROM
            prod
        WHERE
                id_category = 1) p JOIN prod pt
ON
    p.id_product = pt.id_product
WHERE
    pt.id_category != 1
GROUP BY
    pt.id_category
```